# Customize the html output of Django's form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

Whenever you use a {{ form.field.errors }} tag in a Django template, the validation message that is displayed is always surrounded with a unordered list tag. This is not ideal for me. Am I able to modify the surrounding validation message html for a form from a reusable package?

Comment: Note that the unordered list has class `errorlist`, so you can use CSS to style the list as you wish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the django docs about [looping over a form's fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields):

> `{{ field.errors }}`
>   Outputs a `<ul class="errorlist">` containing any validation errors
>   corresponding to this field. You can
>   customize the presentation of the
>   errors with a `{% for error in
>   field.errors %}` loop. In this case,
>   each object in the loop is a simple
>   string containing the error message.

So for example, to wrap each error in `<p>` tags you would do:

```
{% for error in field.errors %}
    <p>{{ error|escape }}</p>    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it still outputs as li, rather them just string

Comment: @DataGreed not according to the docs I've linked to above: *In this case, each object in the loop **is a simple string** containing the error message.*

Comment: Actually you have to iterate over form.non_field_errors to get strings

Comment: `form.non_field_errors` are the errors that do not belong to any specific form field. They are different to `field.errors`, the errors that belong to a particular field.